# Using c3p0 connection pool as data source for persistence

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, persistence, datasource

I've implemented a jBPM project with persistence, using jBoss as the applicational server. I already have a data source, defined in the c3p0 file, and I want to use it as the data source for my persistence unit. The problem is I get the following error:

```
Deployment "persistence.unit:unitName=project.ear/#persUnit" is in error due to the following reason(s): javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: myProjDS not bound
```

I've tested it with the jboss default data source, and everything is working as expected. So, is there anyway I can ignore that defaultDS in the file hsqldb-ds.xml and reference directly the c3p0 defined datasource?

Thanks

Comment: If you are running your app in JBoss, you should not use c3p0. Define the data source in *-ds.xml file and then JBoss will manage the connection pooling for you.

Comment: That is true. I guess I will need to have my datasource specified in the -ds as well. Thank you for your help!